# DDPG: how to implement continuous action space bounded in the interval [-2, 2]?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, ddpg, continuous-action-spaces

I am a newbie in reinforcement learning and trying to understand how to implement continuous actions bounded by $[-2, 2]$. My research shows that doing nothing is a possible solution (i.e. action of 4.5 is mapped to 2 and the action of -3.1 is mapped to -2), but I wonder if there are more elegant approaches.